# AVAudioSession Xcode 6

Tags: xcode, ios8, xcode6, avaudiosession

I just upgraded from Xcode 5 to Xcode 6. I continued working on a project from before, and I got these errors for the following line of code:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: self];
//'setDelegate:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 6.0
//'ViewController *const __strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<AVAudioSessionDelegate>'
```

I am fairly new to Xcode, and I'm not sure what has changed here.

Comment: I actually figured it out for anyone who comes across this. Replace the above with:
    
[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]

Comment: I have the same issue.  I don't understand your solution.  Can you tell me how you resolved the error?